# $A$ is a matrix of 3 rows and 2 columns while $B$ is a matrix of 2 rows and three columns. If $AB=C$ and $BA=D$, then pick the correct option

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Options
>
> A) determinant of C and D are always equal
>
> B) determinant of C is zero
>
> C) determinant of D is zero

The reasoning should be really simple.

$$|C|=|A||B|$$
$$|D|=|B||A|$$

So $$|D|=|C|$$

But the right answer is option b. I have the written explanation for this answer, but I a found it ridiculous and ultimately unsatisfactory. What could be the reason for b) being the answer?

Given solution

> Let $A’$ be a 3x3 matrix with first two columns identical to A and third column has all elements equal to zero. Similarly, construct $B’$ as a 3x3 matrix
>
> $AB=A’B’=C$ $\implies$ $|C|=|A’||B’|=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity for determinant multiplication is only true for square matrices, since other matrices do not have a proper determinant.

What you can do to check if the determinant of a matrix is $0$ is ask - does this matrix have a non-trivial kernel? And indeed, the kernel of $C$ is non-trivial - $B$ sends a $3$ dimensional space into a $2$ dimensional one (which means that some non-zero vector must be mapped to $0$, and no matter what you do later with $A$, you already have a non-trivial kernel (which can only grow with $A$), and so $C$ must have determinant $0$.

Comment: I updated my question to include the given solution. Is it okay to construct a separate square matrix? I am confused regarding the ‘mathematical legality’ of that.

Comment: They showed that you can construct your matrix not only as the original product of non-square matrices, but as a different product of square matrices. It's the same matrix (albeit being a different product), so it must have the same determinant. But since this time you CAN use the product rule for determinants (since the matrices in the product are square), you see directly that the determinant must be $0$. It's 'legal', since you're using the same matrix, only represent it differently.

Comment: The answer you gave is currently beyond my scope. I have absolutely no clue on what you said, but your explanation on the solution is satisfactory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For non-square matrices, the determinant does not make sense, so your statement is false.

But think of $A$ and $B$ as linear homomorphism : $a : \mathbb{K}^2 \to \mathbb{K}^3$ and $b : \mathbb{K}^3 \to \mathbb{K}^2$.
Then $b$ cannot be injective, and $a$ cannot be surjective. Thus $c=a\circ b : \mathbb{K}^3 \to \mathbb{K}^3$ cannot be injective or surjective : as it is an endomorphism, it as a determinant which is forced to be $0$. Consequently $C = AB$ is the matrix of a non-bijective linear endomorphism, so has determinant zero.

**Edit**
Here is an example where $C$ has determinant $0$ but not $D$ :
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \\
B &= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 &0  \end{pmatrix} \\
C &= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
D &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}